# How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((n+1)^k - n^k\right)=0$ when $0<k<1?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How do I prove:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^k - n^k=0,$$ when $0<k<1 ?$

I got a hint:
$$0\leq (n+1)^k - n^k = n^k \left[\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^k - 1\right]$$

Thanks

Comment: If you’ve already covered the mean value theorem, there is a more direct/less clever proof.

Answer (score 2):

What a strange coincidence, I was just thinking about this earlier today.
$$(n+1)^k-n^k=n^k\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k-1\right]$$
$$\leq n^k\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-1\right]$$ because $k<1$.

And this last expression is equal to
$$\frac{1}{n^{1-k}}\to 0$$ again because the exponent on the bottom is positive.

Comment: Thanks. Great way! How do I prove the original series is >=0 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, $0\leq (n+1)^k-n^k $? Also its a sequence not a series. And you need to learn to use latex :-)

Comment: You can left click on formulas to see the underlying latex code.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. What is latex?

Comment: Isnt $n^k\leq (n+1)^k$ obvious ?

Comment: Yeah, I was too tired last night. Thanks a lot!